# Errors with my INSERT Statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

```
void LogData() {
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connecton1"].ConnectionString);
     conn.Open();
     string insertQuery = "insert into LogData (Name, Action, Time, Object) values (@Name. @Action, @Time, @Object)";
     SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
     com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtUsername.Text);
     com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "Logged in");
     com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", DateTime.Now.ToString());
     com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Object", "None");
     com.ExecuteNonQuery();
     conn.Close();
}
```

I am trying to input data into a database to see when people log into my website, but i keep getting a very vague error saying "there Incorrect syntax near '@Action'."  Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Also, am I correctly logging time with "DateTime.Now.ToString()"? I need the time to log down to the second.  For example: `11/3/2014 6:19:13`

Comment: Now that iv fixed the problem by replacing the '.' with a ',' i receive this error. "String or binary data would be truncated." anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Change your Time data type to a DateTime your database, and then pass the @Time parameter as a DateTime (ie instead of DateTime.Now.ToString() just DateTime.Now)

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

`@Name. @Action`

with

```
@Name, @Action
```

Answer (score 1):

In values you have a point before @Action and not semicolon.

Should look like

`Values (@Name,  @Action, @Time, ...`